# Using Accordions and Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, accordion

This question has been asked before but not solved.

I'm using jquery Tabs and Accordion, both on the same page and they simple won't work together.
They work seperate on individual pages, but as soon as theyre on the same page the tabs won't work.
In fact, it flips randomly between which one works and which one doesnt when I reload the page. I'm hoping to nest accordions within tabs using jquery.

Reordering the js loading order doesnt appear to help as some people have had luck doing, though my instinct is its a loading order issue.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="styleguide-tabs-demo-regular">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab One</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab Three</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">Tab 1 content</div>
<div id="tabs-2">Tab 2 content</div>
<div id="tabs-3">Tab 3 content</div>
</div>
<p><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>
<div class="styleguide_demo_accordion1">
<h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
<div>
<div class="styleguide-section__accordion-demo-element">Content for Section 1</div>
</div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
<div>
<div class="styleguide-section__accordion-demo-element">Content for Section 2</div>
</div>
<h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
<div>
<div class="styleguide-section__accordion-demo-element">Content for Section 3</div>
</div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

jquery:

```
$("div.styleguide_demo_accordion1").accordion({header: "h2", collapsible: true, heightStyle: "content", active: false}) 

$("div#customaccordion").accordion({header: "h2", collapsible: true, heightStyle: "content", active: false}) 

$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });

$("div#styleguide-tabs-demo-regular").tabs();
```

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg30296h/) and all I had to change was this line:

```
$("div.styleguide_demo_accordion1").accordion({header: "h2", collapsible: true, heightStyle: "content", active: false})
```

to

```
$("div.styleguide_demo_accordion1").accordion({header: "h3", collapsible: true, heightStyle: "content", active: false})
```

So basically, after changing the `header` option from `h2` to `h3`, it appears to work as intended. Is it possible that you just made a typing error?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its strange because it always 'worked' per se, but not both at the same time. I'm still getting the error even with your fix in my site (I'm coding it in a learning management system) and  believe its possibly a fault somewhere behind the scenes, so I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing strange. There are `<h3>` in HTML while `header: "h2"` in JS
Change all `<h3>` to  `<h2>` or `header: "h2"` to `header: "h3"` and it will be OK